# ProgressDialog not showing when thread is busy

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I have some code that
a) needs about 10..20 seconds to execute
b) returns a value that is used for further processing
c) is called by the user by UI action

Thus I created a program structure like this:

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(ctx);  
pd.setCancelable(false);
pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
pd.setTitle(ctx.getResources().getText(R.string.progress));
pd.setMessage(ctx.getResources().getText(R.string.wait_keygen));
pd.setIndeterminate(true);
pd.show();

returnValue=doSomeDifficultCalculationsHere();

pd.dismiss();
```

Now my problems is: the progress dialogue is not shown, it seems to be blocked by the blocking doSomeDifficultCalculationsHere()-function too.

When I place doSomeDifficultCalculationsHere() into an own thread and do a Thread.join() to wait for result of this function progress dialogue is also not shown because Thread.join() blocks.

When I put the ProgressDialog into the thread I get an exception.

So how else can I solve this problem and let the ProgressDialog be shown when I can't call doSomeDifficultCalculationsHere() really asynchronously because its result is needed for all following steps?

Thanks!

Comment: You want your users to stare at a `ProgressDialog` for 20-30 seconds? You might want to rethink that...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use DialogFragments to display Dialogs.
Second, start this DialogFragment as mentioned in the comments using an AsyncTask. There are methods onPreExecute(...) and onPostExecute(ReturnType) which are running on the MainThread. Use those callbacks to show/hide your dialog. This can be done by:

```
dialogFragment = new MyGreatProgressDialogFragment();
dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "");
...
dialogFragment.dismiss();
```

You can also use events to show/dismiss your dialogs. I can recommend EventBus from GreenRobot (https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

As @codeMagic already mentioned, making the user to wait 30 second is really bad style. There are several thinks you can do.
Try NOT to block the user with a dialog. Show a ProgressBar instead somewhere in your app. If there is no other possibility than making the user wait than you can also show a notification in the notification bar to make clear that the user can leave your app and the process will keep running. Just make sure that the user can do more than just waiting until the process is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use an AsyncTask so the user could leave your App without break the workflow, here an example of how to do this:

```
class startWorkFlow extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        pd.setTitle(ctx.getResources().getText(R.string.progress));
        pd.setMessage(ctx.getResources().getText(R.string.wait_keygen));
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... args ) {
        return doSomeDifficultCalculationsHere();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer i) {
        pd.dismiss();
        continueWorkFlowWith(i);
    }
}
```

and call it with:

```
 new startWorkFlow().execute();
```

be sure that `doSomeDifficultCalculationsHere()` doesn't use variables from the Activity; if this is the case you must pass some parameters to the AsyncTask.